# Automatic adding of double quoting when concating a variable from Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've been struggling with a problem when concating the content of a variable in a bash task in an Azure DevOps pipeline.

What I'm basically trying to achieve is to first create some variables which content comes directly from a json. I create the variables like so:

```
- task: Bash@3
name: variablescreator
displayName: Setting package name, version and extension as variables
inputs:
  targetType: inline
  script: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PACKAGE_NAME]$(jq '.python_wheel_task.package_name' create-job.json)"
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PACKAGE_VERSION]$(jq '.python_wheel_task.version' create-job.json)"
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PACKAGE_EXTENSION]$(jq '.python_wheel_task.extension' create-job.json)"
  workingDirectory: $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/az-devops-pipelines
  failOnStderr: false
```

Then, I want just simply use the content of these variables appending them into shell commands like so:

```
  - task: Bash@3
displayName: Dir python package
inputs:
  targetType: inline
  script: dir
  workingDirectory: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(PACKAGE_NAME)-$(PACKAGE_VERSION)
  failOnStderr: false
```

However, in the outcome, double quotes are added automatically:

```
##[error]Not found workingDirectory: /folder/a/"my_package"-"0.2.2"
```

Any thoughts on how to concat the variables content to shell commands without the quotes being appended?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Have you tried changing doublequotes to singlequotes and vice versa?

Comment: Got the same result. However, I changed variables into parameters and that worked! Similar solution I guess...